# What is the output of this (C-like) pseudo-code using dynamic scoping?

Tags: pseudocode, dynamic-scope

What will be the output of the given pseudo-code using DYNAMIC SCOPING ?
Here I want to know what will be the values of x that will be printed.

It is just simple pseudo code in a language that resembles C but has dynamic scoping.

```
    integer x,y;

    p(integer n){
        x=(n+2)/(n-3);
    }

    q(){
        integer x,y;
        x=3;
        y=4;
        p(y);
        write(x);
    }

    main(){
        x=7;
        y=8;
        q();
        write(x);
    }
```

Comment: I'm asking about the o/p using dynamic scoping. C compilers don't use dynamic scoping. What you answered is using static scoping.

Comment: The whole point of pseudocode is that it does not have a programming language. It just describes an algorithm.  Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Comment: Link you provided also includes C style pseudo code.

Comment: Making it c styled pseudocode helps getting o/p that is why I've kept it that way so that person willing to answer don't have to compile much and can focus on logic of dynamic scoping which I'm not getting.

Comment: The problem here isn't with the pseudocode, it's that you're asking other people to do your work for you without you having made any attempt at it yourself. "which I'm not getting" -- What effort have you made to get it? What exactly don't you get?

Comment: Here are a couple of questions for you that might help: If statically scoped, what variable does `x` refer to in `p`? If dynamically scoped, what variable does `x` refer to in `p`?

Comment: if statically scoped x will refer to global declration and if dynamically scoped x will refer to lastly invoked definition which in this case is of q()'s  @JimBalter

Comment: @JimBalter been looking for the solution since 2 days so thought of putting it over here , hope my solution will help someone like me looking for same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dynamic scope, each identifier has a global stack of bindings. Introducing a local
variable with name x pushes a binding onto the global x stack (which may have been empty), which is popped off when the control flow leaves the scope. Evaluating x in any context always yields the top binding. In other words, a global identifier refers to the identifier associated with the most recent environment. Note that this cannot be done at compile time because the binding stack only exists at runtime, which is why this type of
scoping is called dynamic scoping. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

Having read this theory.. if I answer this question using dynamic scoping
First when main() is called x=7 and y=8 are pushed in stack then when q() is called it pushes x=3 and y=4 ; now p(n) doesn't have x declared so it will use the last invocation of x as declaration which is in q() and will update its value to '6'.

then when scope of q() will end its values will be popped out of stack and globally invoked values of x=7 and x=8 will remain there so x=7 will be printed.

ANS : 6 and 7 are printed

Comment: I totally agree with the explanations, but I think the first value printed will be 0, since p sets the variable to 6/7 (not 6) and as an integer that will be rounded down to zero.

Comment: Yeah man you are completely right I had written '+' instead of '-'
That is fault from my end..have corrected question..

Answer (score 1):

Since I first misunderstood your question and provided an answer for C lexical scope, let's keep it as a comparison.

#### C-style scope

the symbols x and y will correspond to 2 possible variables

Let's call x0, y0 the variables declared at toplevel and xq, yq the ones declared inside q.

```
x0 = 7
y0 = 8
q -> 
   xq = 3
   yq = 4
   p(4) ->
      x0 = 6 // (4+2)/(4-3)
   write(xq) // OUTPUT: 3
write(x0)    // OUTPUT: 6
```

#### dynamic scope

We will show the symbol binding stack to keep track of the symbol current values

```
x0 = 7 // x:(x0)
y0 = 8 // y:(y0)
q ->        // declaring x,y in q -> x:(x0,xq) y:(y0,yq) 
   xq = 3   // x:(x0,xq)
   yq = 4   // y:(y0,yq)
   p(4) ->
      xq = 6 // x:(x0,xq)
   write(xq) // OUTPUT: 6
             // leaving q -> x:(x0) y:(y0)
write(x0)    // OUTPUT: 7
```

This example illustrates well the dangerosity/complexity of dynamic scoping:

from within p, the value of x depends on the execution path and, looking at the code, the only way to know whether we are modifying a local or a global variable is to recreate mentally the flow of the program. This can quickly become quite difficult in moderately more complex cases.

Non-dynamic scoping allows to follow the scope of a given identifier much more easily (simply by tracing back the static scope chain).

Comment: "There is no dynamic scoping in C." -- That's not relevant, since the question is about pseudo-code written in a C-like language, not standard C. It's quite obvious that this is not C since `integer` is not a C type. Your answer is wrong since it uses static, not dynamic, scoping.

Comment: Dang, this is not the most readable question I ever read. I suggest removing "in C" from the question, then.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the try @kuroineko the original answer i've just find a while ago. Have a look and let me know if you have any doubts.